# Flink 1.9 SQL Client throws ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord

Tags: sql, client, apache-flink, classnotfoundexception

Trying to use Flink 1.9 SQL-Client with Kafka without success.
After figuring out about the required jar files and copying them into the lib directory, I am getting the following run-time exception when doing SELECT * FROM table-name:

```
Flink SQL> select * from default_catalog.default_database.member_customer_newsletters ;
[ERROR] Could not execute SQL statement. Reason:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord
```

Doing jar -tf of the jar-file, I can see the class ConsumerRecord being there:

```
jar -tf ./lib/flink-sql-connector-kafka-0.11_2.12-1.9.0.jar|grep 'ConsumerRecord'
org/apache/flink/kafka011/shaded/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/ConsumerRecord.class
```

So, I am not sure why it is trhowing a ClassNotFoundException as the class is already in the jar-file?

I just need to add the run-time is looking for "org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord" but because this jar-file is shaded the full qualified name for the class is "org.apache.flink.kafka011.shaded.org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord.class"

But, this should be true with any other class in this shaded jar as well!

Answer (score 0):

There are two different classes:

```
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord
org.apache.flink.kafka011.shaded.org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord
```

In `flink-sql-connector-kafka-0.11_2.12-1.9.0.jar`, you found the class

```
org.apache.flink.kafka011.shaded.org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord
```

while Flink is complaining about:

```
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord
```

The first is a class used internally by Flink, after a kind of copy-paste from Kafka.

The second one is a class in `kafka-clients-0.11.0.2.jar`.

So Flink is right to complain about a missing library.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, was on vacation. I also did copy your suggested jar into the lib folder before, but same error. Flink 1.7.2 works without your suggested jar. I also thought that this jar should solve the issue, but it does not

Comment: My answer was to explain that Flink is right to complain. It was to explain how to fix the issue.
I have updated my answer.

Comment: The explanation makes sense of course, but what is the solution for it? As mentioned above, I have copied this jar into the lib folder and I am still getting the exact same error. Also, Flink 1.7.2 works without this jar.